# How much energy does it cost to cool an atom to close to 0K?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, temperature, atomic-physics, low-temperature-physics

I read that for many Quantum experiments with Atoms it is necessary to cool them to close to $0K$. How much energy does that cost roughly? Is there a formula which gives a lower bound?

Comment: I suspect the energy required just to maintain the vacuum system far outweighs the atom cooling system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cooling something that's already the coldest thing in the room requires that we actively direct heat transfer away from the object and into a hotter region.

(In contrast, cooling something that's *not* the coldest thing in the room requires us only to put it next to the coldest thing and passively let spontaneous heat transfer occur.)

Unfortunately, the active process removes a lot of entropy from the colder object with nowhere to put it, as transferring the same amount of energy to the hotter surroundings doesn't increase their entropy very much. (In equation form, the entropy transfer $\Delta S=Q/T$, where $Q$ is reversible heat energy and $T$ is temperature. $\Delta S$ is smaller for larger $T$.) The Second Law forbids the destruction of entropy. Therefore, we balance the books by supplying work, which carries no entropy itself but allows us to dump more heat into the surroundings than we actually removed from the colder object.

We write this minimum thermodynamic requirement as $$W=\frac{Q}{\mathrm{COP}}=Q\frac{T_\mathrm{H}-T_\mathrm{C}}{T_C},$$

where $\mathrm{COP}$ is the so-called [coefficient of performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_performance) for our refrigerator and $T_\mathrm{H}$ and $T_\mathrm{C}$ are the so-called hot- and cold-reservoir temperatures. We cannot cool an object from $T_\mathrm{H}$ to $T_\mathrm{C}$ (removing heat $Q$) without expending work $W$ (and for real, inefficient processes, we'll expend more). As described above, this relationship is derived by balancing the books for both energy and entropy. Note that $W$ becomes very large for low $T_\mathrm{C}$ and becomes infinite if we consider the extreme, unfeasible case of cooling something to absolute zero.

Comment: I have one more question though: Once something is cold, doesn't one also have to spend work for maintaining the temperature gradient between the object and the environment? Can one estimate the ammount of work required to do this?

Comment: Yes, if one knows the heat transfer details (e.g., if the object’s insulated, what the temperature of the surroundings are, is forced convection occurring).

Answer (score 0):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_performance

general formula is: efficiency = hot / (hot + cold)

Rule of thumb is something like 'each halving of the temperature requires the same amount of energy', as amount of energy halves, but so does the efficiency.

So as you get closer to the 0 K you need to spend more and more energy to cool it down in our usual environemnt.

Calculate how many halvings of the temperature is needed, and each halving having the same cost. And cost of one halving can be calculated manually.